Get CkEditor4 to set crossorigin attribute on images
I've managed to get CkEditor4 to stop stripping the crossorigin attribute from images by adding it to the plugin add code:
if(!b.plugins.image2){
    CKEDITOR.dialog.add("image",this.path+"dialogs/image.js");
    var a="img[alt,crossorigin,!src]{border-style,border-width,float,height,margin,margin-bottom,margin-left,margin-right,margin-top,width}";
    CKEDITOR.dialog.isTabEnabled(b,"image","advanced")&&(a="img[alt,crossorigin,dir,id,lang,longdesc,!src,title]{*}(*)");

But I don't know how to get CkEditor to add crossorigin="" to all new images added by the image plugin (even better, would bee to existing images loaded in the editor as well, though I'll settle for just new images).
